# Get Phone Number(android) in Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

How can I get phone number in android?

Sample Code:

```
var contacts = Titanium.Contacts.getAllPeople();
Titanium.API.log(contacts[0].phone['mobile'][0]); //in iOS, returns "01012345678" fine :)
Titanium.API.log(contacts[0].phone['mobile'][0]); //in Android, returns ""  :(
Titanium.API.log(contacts[0].fullName); //in Android & iOS, returns "test Name" fine :)
Titanium.API.log(contacts[0].phone); //in Android, returns "" :(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, It worked with me

```
//Getting all the contacts
var people = Ti.Contacts.getAllPeople();

//Getting the total number of contacts
var totalContacts = people.length;
//Checking whether the contact list is empty or not
if( totalContacts > 0 )
{
    for( var index = 0; index < totalContacts; index++ )
    {
       //Holding the details of a single contact
       var person = people[index];
      Ti.API.info("Mobile -> " + person['phone'].mobile + " home-> " + person['phone'].home);
    }
}
```

note that your phone should have contact number in mobile and home options. I've added a screen shot from my android emulator. Just try giving numbers like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. It scans all the contact numbers from the phone book whether it is mobile or home or anything else. Code also removes all non-digit characters from the number too:

```
var people = Ti.Contacts.getAllPeople();
for (var i=0, ilen=people.length; i<ilen; i++)
{
    var person = people[i];
    for(var temp in person.phone)
    {
        var temp_numbers = person.phone[temp];
        for(var k=0;k<temp_numbers.length; k++)
        {
            var temp_num = temp_numbers[k];
            temp_num = temp_num.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
        }
    }
}
```