# How can I programmatically get the contact list of Android/iPhone using titanium

Tags: android, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

How can I programmatically get the contact list of Android/iPhone using `titanium`,  I need this for read only purpose.

I already checked this [Can I get a user's phone number using any of the Titanium API's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065911/can-i-get-a-users-phone-number-using-any-of-the-titanium-apis), but I like to open it using my app and then dial a call to the selected number, my app will not perform any other action(edit, delete) on the number. Is that possible in Android and iPhone using titanium or simple Android and iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to gain access to contacts as described [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts).

After that it is possible to get all contacts via [`getAllPeople`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts-method-getAllPeople)

This works for both iOS and Android.

Performing a call works simple on Android (you should create a Phone Call [Intent](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Intent) with `Ti.Android.ACTION_DIAL`). On iOS you simply need display the number and the system should link it to a call action. If not you can add a listener to the element:

```
label.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  Ti.Platform.openURL('tel:<number');
});
```

Comment: Note that in Android, getAllPeople() is very slow and consume a lot of memory, as each person returned gets his own proxy. If you only need specific info, I recommend writing a native module.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your phone contacts using [showContacts](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts-method-showContacts) method as follows

```
Titanium.Contacts.showContacts(); //Will display the native contacts in both iphone and android
```

In the case of iphone, you should need the access permission for contacts. You can check for the permission as follows

```
if (Ti.Contacts.contactsAuthorization == Ti.Contacts.AUTHORIZATION_AUTHORIZED){
    //You've authorization
    //Some code here
} else if (Ti.Contacts.contactsAuthorization == Ti.Contacts.AUTHORIZATION_UNKNOWN){
    Ti.Contacts.requestAuthorization(function(e){
    //Authorization is unknown so requesting for authorization
    if (e.success) {
            //You've authorization
            //Some code here
        } else {
            //No authorization hence you cannot access contatcs
        }
    });
} else {
    //No authorization hence you cannot access contatcs
}
```

For more details refer [Titanium Contacts module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts).

`Ti.Contacts.getAllPeople` will also do the same, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874175/get-phone-numberandroid-in-titanium/12890942#12890942) link also

Answer (score 0):

```
$.index.open();
var people = Titanium.Contacts.getAllPeople();
var totalContacts = people.length;
Ti.UI.setBackgroundColor('#F0FFFF');
var data = [];
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'white',
});

var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : "50dp",
    width : "100%",
    top : '0dp',
    backgroundColor : '#050505',
});

var text = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text : "Contact Book",
    left : 20,
    color : '#fff'

});

view.add(text);
win.add(view);

var template = {
    childTemplates : [{
        type : 'Ti.UI.Button',
        bindId : 'image',
        properties : {
            left : '2dp',
            backgroundImage : 'appicon.png',
        }
    }, {
        type : 'Ti.UI.Label',
        bindId : 'rowtitle',
        properties : {
            left : '70dp'
        }
    }]
};
if( totalContacts > 0 )
{ 
    for( var index = 0; index < totalContacts; index++ )
    {
         var person = people[index];
        Titanium.API.info(person.fullName);
        //table.add(person.fullName);
        if(person.fullName != null){
            data.push({
                rowtitle : {
                    text :person.fullName
                },

            });
        }
    }
}

var listView = Ti.UI.createListView({
    top : '55dp',
    templates : {
        'plain' : template
    },

    defaultItemTemplate : 'plain',
});

var section = Ti.UI.createListSection({
    items : data
});

listView.sections = [section];

win.add(listView);
win.open();
```